# How to add a tag before each item of a list?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add number bullets to list items to practice on jQuery functions. I can't see what's wrong with the code but it's not working.

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
<body>
<ui>
<li>Html Tutorial</li>
<li>Mongodb Tutorial</li>
    <li>Python Tutorial</li></ui>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var i = 0
        var listItems = $("li").each(function() {listItems[i].prepend("<b>" + i + "</b>"); i++;});;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: using <ol>
<li>Html Tutorial</li>
<li>Mongodb Tutorial</li>
    <li>Python Tutorial</li></ol> may solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `listItems` variable's value is set after the `.each()` method iterates over all the collection elements. In the `each` callback function `listItems` variable is still `undefined`.

It could be:

```
var i = 0
var listItems = $("li");
listItems.each(function() {listItems[i].prepend("<b>" + i + "</b>"); i++;});
```

But using bracket notation (`[index]`), the returned element is a DOM element that doesn't have `.prepend()` method. You should either use the `.eq()` method which returns a jQuery object (`listItems.eq(i)`) or wrap the element with jQuery constructor and create a jQuery object for using the jQuery object's `.prepend()` method:

```
$(listItems[i]).prepend("<b>" + i + "</b>");
```

The second parameter of the `each` handler and the `this` of it refers to the current element, there is no need to cache the collection and use the bracket notation.

```
$("li").each(function(index) { $(this).prepend("<b>" + index + "</b>") });
```

Also the tag name is `ul` (*unordered list*) not `ui`. If you want to have an *ordered* list you can use an `ol` (*ordered list*) tag which by default adds the numbers.

```
<ol>
    <li>Html Tutorial</li>
    <li>Mongodb Tutorial</li>
    <li>Python Tutorial</li>
</ol>
```

However, by default, numbering starts from `1`. You can set the [`start`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/the-ol-element.html#attr-ol-start) attribute value to `0`:

```
<ol start="0">
    <li>Html Tutorial</li>
    <li>Mongodb Tutorial</li>
    <li>Python Tutorial</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following,

```
var i = 1;
   $("li").each(function(){
   $(this).prepend("<b>"+i+" </b>");
   i++;
});
```

Also, you should be using ul not ui.

Also I think the best way to acheive what you want is using `<ol>`